# SQL left join with 2 or more count group

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table

```
ID   catone   cattwo
100    2        1
100    3        1
200    1        2
```

expect result (count not sum)

```
ID    totalcat1    totalcat2
100     2             2
200     1             1
```

My query

```
  select COUNT(*) as totalcat1, catone  
  from Table1 
  group by cat1
  left join
  select COUNT(*) as totalcat2, cattwo  
  from Table1 
  group by cattwo
```

Try to have both count columns catone and cattwo 
Not sure how to correct it. Thank you

Comment: Some sample data and expected results would help. Its not clear how to handle the fact that there could be a different number of Cat1 and Cat2 values.

Comment: provide some sample data with your desired output

Comment: Show us an edge case, i.e. when the count is different...

Comment: Expected count per cat is still the same, show us how it would be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple group-by should do it

```
select ID, COUNT(catone) as totalcat1, COUNT(cattwo) as totalcat2  
  from Table1 
  group by ID;
```

Note that this simply counts the number of values that are not NULL. If your original data was this...

```
ID   catone   cattwo
100    2        1
100    3        1
100    4        NULL
```

... then the result would be

```
ID    totalcat1    totalcat2
100     3             2
```

If you want to count the *distinct* values - so totalcat2 would be 1 (as only 1 value exists in that column, although it's there twice) you could use

```
select ID, COUNT(DISTINCT catone) as totalcat1, COUNT(DISTINCT cattwo) as totalcat2  
  from Table1 
  group by ID;
```

which would return totalcat1 = 3 and totalcat2 = 1.

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d6ca8e429e637f2156bc39d317129410) with the two options.

Here's a second [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bb3b687496009da2db7d7ff1c606f4a6) on request of OP with ID 200.

Comment: what about id 200?

Comment: It works fine with ID 200.. I'll add it to the fiddle.